# Sudo prevents the following command from executing

Tags: linux, bash, unix, sudo

I have been facing inconsistent behaviour between two versions of sudo for the following scenario:

```
$ sudo sleep 5
echo "hi"  # during the 5 seconds
```

On one system, with sudo version `1.8.21p2`, this buffers the second command and runs it afterwards -- but on a newer version (`1.9.9`), it doesn't:

```
$ sudo --version
Sudo version 1.9.9
...
$ sudo sleep 5
echo 'hi'
$
```

```
$ sudo --version
Sudo version 1.8.21p2
...
$ sudo sleep 5
echo 'hi'
$ echo 'hi'
hi
```

I found this bug which is relevant: https://bugzilla.sudo.ws/show_bug.cgi?id=786, however the discussion there suggests that this was fixed in version 1.8.20. Has it possibly been reintroduced between 1.8.20 and 1.9.9? If so, what could be a workaround?

*Edit*: to clarify, both of those were run after running a `sudo` command and providing the user password

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Ubuntu 22.04, the `use_pty` option is on in supplied `/etc/sudoers` file, which has this effect.

Comment: This seems to be the default on the newer `sudo`, and this solved the problem